# Go workerpool implementation using errgroup, goroutines stuck

Tags: go

I have implemented a workerpool pattern using errgroup, so that error in any goroutines can be caught. Here is my detail:

```
    jobs := make(chan UsersInfo, totalUsers)
    results := make(chan UsersInfo, totalUsers)

    g, gCtx := errgroup.WithContext(ctx)

    for i := 1; i <= 4; i++ {
        g.Go(func() error {
            err := workerUser(gCtx, jobs, results)
            if err != nil {
                return err
            }
            return nil
        })
    }

    for _, user := range usersResp {
        jobs <- user
    }
    close(jobs)

    var usersArray []UsersInfo
    for  i := 1; i <= totalUsers; i++ {
        r := <-results
        usersArray = append(usersArray, r)
    }

    if err := g.Wait(); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
```

Then the worker function implemented like this:

```
func workerUser(ctx context.Context, jobs <-chan UsersInfo, results chan<- UsersInfo) error {
  for {
    select {
    case <-ctx.Done():
        return ctx.Err()
    case user, _ := <-jobs:
        userInfo, err := CallUserAPI(ctx, user)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        results <- userInfo
    }
 }
}
```

The CallUserAPI return 403 Forbidden error which should invoke g.wait() and should stop all goroutines instantly when there is non-nil error. But this is not the case here, g.wait() is never called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of problems:

- The loop

  ```
    for  i := 1; i <= totalUsers; i++ {
        r := <-results
        usersArray = append(usersArray, r)
    }
  ```

  waits for the workers to send a result for each user.  That will not happen when `CallUserAPI` returns an error.
- The worker does not handle the case where `jobs` is closed.

Here's code that fixes both of these problems:

Declare a type that specifies the user to work on and where to put the result:

```
type job struct {
    user UsersInfo
    result *UsersInfo
}
```

Modify the worker to use this new type. Also, modify the worker to exit when `jobs` is closed.

```
func workerUser(ctx context.Context, jobs <-chan job) error {
    for {
        select {
        case <-ctx.Done():
            return ctx.Err()
        case job, ok := <-jobs:
            if !ok {
                // No more jobs, exit.
                return nil
            }
            var err error
            *job.result, err = CallUserAPI(ctx, job.user)
            if err != nil {
                return err
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Glue it all together in the main goroutine:

```
jobs := make(chan UsersInfo, totalUsers)
usersArray := make([]UsersInfo, totalUsers)
g, gCtx := errgroup.WithContext(ctx)

// Start the workers.
for i := 1; i <= 4; i++ {
    g.Go(func() error {
        return workerUser(gCtx, jobs)
    })
}

// Feed the workers.  
for i, user := range usersResp {
    jobs <- job{user: user, result: &usersArray[i]}
}

// Close the channel to indicate that no more jobs will be sent.
// The workers exit via the `if !ok { return nil }` statement.
close(jobs)

// Wait for the workers to complete.
if err := g.Wait(); err != nil {
    return nil, err
}

// It is now safe to access the results in usersArray.
```